# Upload file to google drive using php and retrieve the link?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I can upload my file to google drive using php but I can't retrieve the link. Here's my php code for uploading the file to google drive :

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
foreach ($files as $file_name) {
    $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
    $file->setTitle($file_name);
    $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
    $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
    $service->files->insert(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
            'mimeType' => $mime_type
        )
    );
}
finfo_close($finfo);
header('location:'.$url);exit;
```

Comment: What is the value of `$url`?

Comment: go to index.php

Comment: Which version of the api are you using?

Comment: php 7.2.9 installed in my localhost

Comment: I ment which version of the google api.

Comment: using version 2

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research and according to google, this should be it:

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
foreach ($files as $file_name) {
    $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
    $file->setTitle($file_name);
    $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
    $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
    $upload = $service->files->insert(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
            'mimeType' => $mime_type,
            'fields' => 'embedLink'
        )
    );
}
finfo_close($finfo);
header('location:' . $upload->fields);exit;
```

As you can see I added `'fields' => 'embedLink'` which requests for the embed link. `fields` has a lot of different functions but this one seems relevant to your question.

I'm not sure if `$upload->fields` is going to work or not because I've only tested it on google's emulator which doesn't show me any code. The link is supposed to be sent back in the response (in JSON format), so you might have to use `json_decode()` to get the data. You can also try `$upload->embedLink`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - what have you changed, and why? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer